# Ektron cms 400.net version 8.02 send ecommerce data to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, ektron

I am want to send ecommerce data to google analytics. My site is built on Ektron cms 400.net version 8.02. Please help me to get shopping data and send it to google analytics on click event of checkout button.

Comment: welcome to stack please show us what you have tried and we will try to assist you with any issues you may have  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: Hi I am new to Ektron CMS and read CMS documentation but does not get any code sample to access shopping data.

Comment: you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask we are unfortunately not here to do your work for you we are here to help you when you get stuck.   If you need help with Ektron cms you may want to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

Even thought you're running on ektron you're going to want to set this up as you would with any site using the ecommerce tracking part of google analytics. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce